# sort_values() in Pandas behaves contrary to documentation

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am puzzled with the behavior of sort_values() in Pandas which does not seem to respond appropriately to the axis argument.

For a toy example:

```
toy.to_json()
'{"labels":{"0":7,"1":4,"2":7,"3":1,"4":5,"5":0,"6":3,"7":1,"8":4,"9":9},"companies":{"0":"Apple","1":"AIG","2":"Amazon","3":"American express","4":"Boeing","5":"Bank of America","6":"British American Tobacco","7":"Canon","8":"Caterpillar","9":"Colgate-Palmolive"}}'

toy.sort_values('labels') # this works alright
labels  companies
5   0   Bank of America
3   1   American express
7   1   Canon
6   3   British American Tobacco
1   4   AIG
8   4   Caterpillar
4   5   Boeing
0   7   Apple
2   7   Amazon
9   9   Colgate-Palmolive

toy.sort_values(by = 'labels', axis = 1) # Returns an exception
KeyError: 'labels'
```

Comment: From doc: *"if axis is 1 or ‘columns’ then by may contain column levels and/or index labels
"*. `'labels'` is a column label, so should work with `axis=0`.

Comment: What are you expecting that result of axis=1 based sorting to be?

Comment: Your indexes are `5, 3, 7, 6, 1....`. If you had a row with an index named `labels`, It would work too. But you don't, so it raises an exception telling you it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on an example to the above comments and answers:

Lets assume you had a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"labels":{"0":7,"1":4,"2":7,"3":1,"4":5},"companies":{"0":9,"1":1,"2":6,"3":1,"4":8}})
>>df
    labels  companies
0   7       9
1   4       1
2   7       6
3   1       1
4   5       8
```

For `axis=0`, it would sort when you pass a index levels and/or column labels as:

```
df.sort_values(by='labels')
```

which gives you a sorted `label` column (ascending by default).

```
   labels   companies
3   1       1
1   4       1
4   5       8
0   7       9
2   7       6
```

Coming to `axis=1` , refer to the below code:

```
df.sort_values('4',axis=1)
```

This will sort the columns in a way the `index 4` is sorted. Here it wont change anything since for `index 4` since `5` is less than `8` and by default the sorting is `ascending`. However if you execute `df.sort_values('1',axis=1)` where the value under `label` is more than `companies`, you will see that the position of `labels` and `companies` has been exchanged.

```
    companies   labels
0   9           7
1   1           4
2   6           7
3   1           1
4   8           5
```

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

This is because axis 0 is "down" in your example, and 1 is "right" (that is, across columns)
If you look at the documentation for [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), you see that the first argument is indeed `by`, and the default vaule for `axis` is 0. 
So your repeat your first example, you need to execute `toy.sort_values(by='labels', axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to get understanding around axis and rows to clear when we choose `axis=1` or `axis=0`.

```
df.shape[0]  # gives number of row count
df.shape[1]  # gives number of col count
```

Let's assume a dataFrame as follow:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
...     'col2' : [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
...     'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
... })

>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    A     1     1
2    B     9     9
3  NaN     8     4
4    D     7     2
5    C     4     3
```

So, applying the df.shape and see how it turns around the columns & rows:

```
>>> df.shape[0]
6            <-- Here, we have six row into the dataFrame
>>> df.shape[1]
3            <-- Here, we have three columns into the dataFrame
```

Now if you are just sorting the value by column name hence you don't need to specify `axis=1` because column name already been specified,  you can do simply :

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    A     1     1
2    B     9     9
5    C     4     3
4    D     7     2
3  NaN     8     4
```

or, you can pass multiple column names as a list with `by` :

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
  col1  col2  col3
1    A     1     1
0    A     2     0
2    B     9     9
5    C     4     3
4    D     7     2
3  NaN     8     4
```